# List<>.OrderBy doesn't seem to order my List

Tags: c#, list

*** I have just spotted my error! Sorry guys! See the end of the question for the solution, or keep reading for fun to spot the issue ***

I am trying to return a List<> based on a property of the objects called 'Weight'.

I am trying this:

```
public List<ReferenceTypeDto> GetAllResourceTypes()
{
    var unordered = rd.GetAllResourceTypes();
    var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(t => t.Weight).ToList();
    return ordered;

}
```

But the order doesn't seem to change. What am I doing wrong?

The method I call is defined like this:

```
public List<ReferenceTypeDto> GetAllResourceTypes()
{
    var types = (from c in _context.resource_type
                 select new ReferenceTypeDto
                     {
                         Description = c.Description,
                         Id = c.Id
                     }).ToList();
    return types;
}
```

And a ReferenceTypeDto is defined like this:

```
public class ReferenceTypeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

*** Error spotted! I forgot to assign the 'Weight' value to the property of the object I am sorting!! Sorry for waisting your time... ***

Comment: it seems ok to me.. are you sure that you are comparing 'rd' and 'ordered' to evaluate if it is ordered?

Comment: Is it ordered in the wrong direction or is it exactly the same as `unordered`?

Comment: What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: What is the data type of `Weight`? If it's a string, then it would be ordered alphabetically, not numerically.

Comment: I've tested this code for a weight of type int, and it worked properly, with focus on the OrderBy and not the GetAllResourceTypes usage. I believe your issue is in that area, try testing the ordering alone and see that it works.

Comment: Thanks guys. Going to see what is going on. Not sure why I got a negative vote for the question. Any idea?

Comment: I've added the method that gets the data, as well as the data type I am sorting, which is based on an Int.

Comment: Sorry guys! It was a silly error by me.... Forgot to set the property in my Class. Sorry for wasting your time, guys. Silly error.

Comment: It would have been nice if that were to have thrown a `NullReferenceException`!

Answer (score 1):

There is one case I have come across where this happens. This happens when I think I want to order by a particular field but what I wanted all along is to order in a descending manner. If your items are already sorted ascending...ly, then calling `OrderBy` won't change the order.

Since you have a field called `Weight` I can only assume you want higher weights to be at the top of your list. This is a good candidate for a descending order sort.

Give this code a shot and see if this is what you want:

```
public List<ReferenceTypeDto> GetAllResourceTypes()
{
    var unordered = rd.GetAllResourceTypes();
    var ordered = unordered.OrderByDescending(t => t.Weight).ToList();
    return ordered;
}
```

If that does not work, then I believe I understand why swapneel suggested their code. As discussed with Matt Johnson, it is possible that you are using an underlying query provider that implements `OrderBy` incorrectly. On the basis that two individuals have pointed out that this may be the case, I suggest the following additional test:

```
public List<ReferenceTypeDto> GetAllResourceTypes()
{
    var unordered = rd.GetAllResourceTypes().ToList();
    var ordered = unordered.OrderByDescending(t => t.Weight).ToList();
    return ordered;
}
```

If the second example works, please do give credit to swapneel or Matt Johnson since their theories solved your issue and I simply elaborated and connected conversational dots.

Comment: Both versions seem to return the same order. The order isn't changing for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know the return type of `rd.GetAllResourceTypes()`.

If it's just a simple `List<T>`, then your code should be working.

But perhaps it is an `IQueryable<T>`?  If so, it is up to the underlying LINQ provider to decide whether or not (and how) it supports ordering.  If you are using LINQ-to-Entities (Entity Framework), then it should be implemented.  But perhaps you are accessing a custom LINQ provider?

You didn't tell us anything about where the data is coming from, so its impossible to know for sure.

Comment: I believe that `IQueryable<T>` inherits its extension methods from `IEnumerable<T>`. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` correctly. All the `IQueryable<T>` implementation does is build a filter based on an expression tree for the underlying enumerator. It is quite possible, as you have mentioned, that the underlying query provider may simply implement `OrderBy` incorrectly. This could very well be the case with a non-standard ORM.

Comment: @Michael - There are plenty of non-orm uses for linq.  Examples: linq-to-XML, or nosql databases like RavenDB which translates linq to Lucene.  There are others listed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/02/28/link-to-everything-a-list-of-linq-providers.aspx).  So its hard to be certain without knowing what provider he's talking about.

Comment: Matt, I was pointing out the likely case. Do note that I did not specify that it is related to a non-standard ORM but rather that it is only one possibility. Of course there are tons of uses for LINQ.

Comment: @Michael - So from the OP's comments, it looks like it was EF and just a data error.  But nice speculating with you! :)